# Function composition help

Tags: calculus

Question:
Find $(f * g)(3)$ and $(g * f)(3)$

$f(x)=-3x-1; g(x)=x^2-2$

The answer I got was $-9x^3-3x^2+18x+6$.
I was wondering if I did this right? If not, can someone show me step by step how to get the answer?

It seems that my question is about composition, but my incorrect answer was done by multiplying the functions since I didn't really understand the concept of composition.

Comment: By *multiply* you mean *function composition*? You should use mathjax for math equations, It makes them very much more clear

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That's why I think that the OP's question is about composition and not multiplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $f(x)=-3x-1$ and $g(x)=x^2-2$

$(f\circ g)(3)=f(g(3))=-22$

$(g\circ f)(3)=g(f(3))=98$